# How does multi-threading work in Python 3.4?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I am just playing around with multi-threading, but I can't seem to get it to work. I have looked at other questions, but none really help me. Here's my code so far:

```
import threading, time

def hello():
    for i in range(1,5):
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Hello")

def world():
    for i in range(1,5):
        time.sleep(1)
        print("World")

newthread = threading.Thread(hello())
newthread.daemon = True
newthread.start()
otherthread = threading.Thread(world())
otherthread.daemon = True
otherthread.start()
print("end")
```

I expect to get something like:

```
Hello
World
Hello
World
Hello
World
Hello
World
end
```

But instead I get:

```
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
World
World
World
World
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
import threading, time

def hello():
    for i in range(1,5):
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Hello")

def world():
    for i in range(1,5):
        time.sleep(1)
        print("World")

newthread = threading.Thread(target=hello)
newthread.start()
otherthread = threading.Thread(target=world)
otherthread.start()

# Just for clarity
newthread.join()
otherthread.join()

print("end")
```

The joins tell the main thread to wait on the other threads before exiting. If you want the main thread to exit without waiting set `demon=True` and don't join. The output might surprise you a little bit, it's not as clean as you might expect. For example I got this output:

```
HelloWorld

World
 Hello
World
 Hello
WorldHello
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, worked perfectly, and I added a small delay between starting the threads to make the output correct. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
threading.Thread(hello())
```

You called the function `hello` and passed the result to `Thread`, so it executed before the thread object even existed. Pass the plain function object:

```
threading.Thread(target=hello)
```

Now the `Thread` will be responsible for executing the function.

Comment: After removing the brackets, I now get this error:

    newthread = threading.Thread(hello, None)
AssertionError: group argument must be None for now

Comment: add `target=hello` as parameters. This tells it to execute the function. Also add `args=(arg1, arg2, arg3)` for parameters.

Comment: You also need `daemon = False` or the script will exit before the threads finish.

Comment: Thanks for the help